# NosuchMethod error: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, groovy

I'm using a grails application. While deploying my application into tomcat container, I get an error saying: `log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite`. I was able to deploy it without any issues all these days but now I see this error. The only change I have done as part of config is that I added a properties file. Unable to figure out what the issue is. Any clues?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:74)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:159)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper.<clinit>(ConfigurationHelper.groovy:41)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.createGrailsApplication(Log4jConfigListener.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with a malformed config file some months ago

Comment: @chf Resolved it. It was because I had included http-builder in my buildconfig.groovy. This was overriding the groovy version that I was using. I just had to enforce this jar to exclude groovy. That fixed it!

Comment: Thank you for the update and sharing your solution

Comment: I am getting the same error. Mine is a maven project and I am getting error on this line   public static final String username = System.getenv("Username"). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks